# Is there a way to define max and min value (number)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to define a max amount e.g. 3 and a min amount e.g. 0 to a variable?

So we have `let n = 0;` and I want it, when I click on a button it adds 1, I mean `n++;` and subtracts 1 when I click on the other button(`n--;`).

I tried this `n = Math.max(0 , min(3, n + 1));` but wasn't useful.

I'm making a photo slider so n is gonna be the value: `Object.values(foo)[n]`.

I would be happy if you give me another way to answer but don't forget to answer it the way I want :D

This is my code:

```js
let n = 0;

const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  n++;
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});

document.querySelector('.substract').addEventListener('click', () => {
  n--;
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="substract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return early from your listeners.

```js
let n = 0;

const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (n === 3) return;
  n++;
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});

document.querySelector('.substract').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (n === 0) return;
  n--;
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="substract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```

Comment: I think I'm gonna accept this answer, the most simple and easiest way. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a conditional before assigning the value

```js
let n = 0;

const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  n = n<3 ? n+1 : n;   // -------- Conditional
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});

document.querySelector('.substract').addEventListener('click', () => {
  n = n>0 ? n-1 : n;   // -------- Conditional
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="substract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to be a one-liner, you can make a simple function that has `if` statements to check the range. I modified your code with a `changeN` function to do this.

```js
let n = 0;

function changeN(x) {
  n += x;
  if (n > 3) n = 3;
  if (n < 0) n = 0;
}
const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeN(1);
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});

document.querySelector('.substract').addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeN(-1);
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="substract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using a `getter` and `setter`:

```js
let yourNObj = {
 value : 0,
 get val(){
   return this.value;
 },
 set val(newVal){
 if(newVal >= 0 && newVal<=3){
   this.value = newVal;
 }
 }
}

const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  yourNObj.val++;
  result.textContent = `n is ${yourNObj.val}`;
});

document.querySelector('.substract').addEventListener('click', () => {
  yourNObj.val--;
  result.textContent = `n is ${yourNObj.val}`;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="substract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to limit the number - and also you could use the **same** event listener for both buttons and not have to duplicate code. Just give both buttons a similar class and 'sniff' for which one is which in the listener.

```js
let n = 0, max = 3, min = 0;

const result = document.querySelector('h2');

document.querySelectorAll('.calc').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let inc = e.target.classList.contains('add') ? 1 : -1;
  n += inc;
  n = Math.min(n, max);
  n = Math.max(n, min);
  result.textContent = `n is ${n}`;
}));
```

```html
<button type="button" class="calc subtract">substract</button>
<button type="button" class="calc add">add</button>

<h2></h2>

<p>The min amount should be : 0<br>The max amount should be : 3</p>
```